# Virtualenvwrapper environments not visible in finder or terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Using OSX 10.9.2

Just getting to grips with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. I am having an issue where the environments I create with virtualenv are visible in both terminal and finder, but environments that I create with virtualenvwrapper are not.

Here are the steps I take in terminal.

```
virtualenv virt_env/virt1 --no-site-packages
```

Successfully creates a virtualenv called virt1

```
source virt1/bin/activate
```

Activates the virtualenv

```
(virt1)localhost:virt_env brendan$
```

I have several of these virtual environments set up and working and I am able to install packages in each, as I would expect. I am able to switch between them and remove them as necessary. I am also able to see them in Finder and in Terminal.

However when I create virtual environments using virtualenvwrapper it appears that I am able to work with them but I am not able to see them.

Here are the steps I take with virtualenvwrapper

```
localhost:~ brendan$ mkvirtualenv virt_env/virt4
New python executable in virt_env/virt4/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
(virt4)localhost:~ brendan$
```

I am able to work with this e.g.

```
(virt4)localhost:~ brendan$ sudo easy_install yolk
```

And I am able to deactivate and reactivate it. e.g.

```
deactivate
localhost:~ brendan$ 
workon virt_env/virt4
(virt4)localhost:~ brendan$
```

But when I go to finder I am only able to see the environments (virt1, virt2, virt3) that I created via virtualenv and not the environments (virt4) that I created using virtualenvwrapper

I am using these tutorials

[Virtualenv](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/)
[Virtualenvwrapper](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2012/7/24/Getting-Started-with-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-in-Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you've defined your `WORKON_HOME` environment variable to tell virtualenvwrapper where to put your environments (see the [documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction))

Comment: Ill take a look at this now shortly. So unlike virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper stores all its environments in one place?

Comment: Yep, and that's a good thing, you shouldn't really need to be digging around in your virtualenvs, they're implementation details. If you must `cdsitepackages` can be adapted to solve most problems.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS X is a Unix-based system, and so doesn't list files and directories whose names begin with a dot. You are probably storing your virtualenvs is a directory called .virtualenvs, which is therefore invisible.

For details of how to find the pesky thing see, for example, http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/quickly-show-hidden-files.php

Comment: mkvirtualenv virt_env/virt4 does not have a "." before the virt4. Also I have set all my hidden files to visable via defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES and relaunched my finder. still not working